# Can I create a Subversion repository starting at another number?

Tags: svn

I want to create a new repo where the value of the revision is whatever I want it to be.

`svnadmin create REPOS_PATH --rev-number-to-start 10,000`

Like you do with a check book.

Comment: Have you tried to `svnadmin dump` you repository and then modify `Revision-number:` field in resulting dump? Perhaps this will do the trick.

Comment: Ah ha! and I can create an empty new repo to dump!

Comment: Dang.  I thought your were stating that in a svnadmin dump I could specify the rev number

Comment: Not so easy :) You need to hack the dump file itself. Perhaps it will break things...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure each rev has to exist even if it's empty.  I tried doing svnadmin create and the hacking the `[repo]/db/current` file up to 10k but that doesn't work because none of the revs are there.

Only way I could do it was to create a repository with a bunch of revisions, dump them, filter out everything and then load the filtered "empty" dump file.

```
for n in {0..4999}; do echo "--- $n"; svn mkdir fake; svn ci -m ""; svn rm fake; svn ci -m ""; done
svnadmin dump /path/to/repo > repo-10k.dump
svnadminfilter include zzz < repo-10k.dump > repo-10k-empty.dump
svnadmin create newrepo
svnadmin load newrepo < repo-10k-empty.dump
```

Comment: Great answer and thanks for adding the bash script.  I'm going to let this question stew a couple more days.  But through my own research I came to the same conclusion that you did.

Comment: yeah probably wouldn't be too hard to make a script to create the empty dump file.  or just create a big enough fake repo that you can selectively dump 1-999 or 1-99999 for different starting points.

Comment: out of curiosity what's the motivation for starting at rev 10,000 or what have you?

Comment: I have a repo I want to export head, and start a new repo.  But, I don't want to forget (Psychologically speaking) about the road that lead there...