# 5gb SVN repository fails to import

Tags: svn

We have SVN repository that is 5GB when it is exported. Due to its size it fails to import/load on another server or anywhere.

The history of changes in this repository is not important. We need only the final/current state of the folder.

Is it possible to remove the history of changes, leaving us only the current, considerably smaller, state so that we can import elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty on this but I think you can svnadmin dump less revs and just import those.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about bringing history over, use `svn export` with the root URL of the repository to pull a copy of everything at the current `HEAD` revision.

Then `svn import` the resulting directory tree into your new repository.

That said, a 5GB Subversion dumpfile isn't really that large and you may want to investigate *why* you're unable to load it in a new server. Error messages should be produced by `svnadmin load` - start with those.

Comment: If you're interested in preserving the revision number for any reason, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030041/can-i-create-a-subversion-repository-starting-at-another-number/7033319#7033319